# How to convert .htaccess to web.config?

Tags: windows, .htaccess, iis, server, web-config

I am realy lost here. I am used to work with linux server so I use .htaccess
Now I need to develop a project in windows server and I need to use some rewrite rules, etc. So I need to set the web.config file.

So I need help to convert my .htaccess rules to web.config
This are the rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^box/camp(.+)?/?$ /_box/access_box_files/camp$1
RewriteRule ^box/merchant(.+)?/?$ /box/access_box_files/merchant$1

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_tab=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**UPDATE**

```
RewriteRule ^box/camp(.+)?/?$ /_box/access_box_files/camp$1
```

In this case I need that whenever the URL is "/box/camp" there is access to "/_box/access_box_files/cam" and that all the information that comes in front of "(.+)?" "$1" is included. Without changing the URL in the browser, or forwarding the user.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_tab=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In this case, any information that comes in the URL must be collected in a variable.
For example:
https:// website dot com/tab1/tab2/tab3
I will get the information in: $_GET['url_tab'] which would have the information: "tab1/tab2/tab3".

```
RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In this case it is to force the URL to be loaded with https.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: You need to explain in natural language exactly what your requirements are. Those who know IIS/web.config may not necessarily speak Apache config as well. (Just as you don't speak web.config.)

Comment: _Aside:_ Although your existing directives are a bit ambiguous and in the wrong order, so they shouldn't be converted literally. `^box/camp(.+)?/?$` is the same as `^box/camp(.*)` (so maybe that's not doing quite what you think it is?). And the HTTP to HTTPS redirect should be the first rule, not the last. Any HTTP to HTTPS redirect (except for static resources) is going to expose `index.php`.

Comment: Hi @MrWhite thank you for you comment. I add more information. Everything is working well in linux server, so I just need it to work in windows server as well. Thank very much.

Comment: IIS allows you import apache url rewrite rule and converts to IIS url rewrite rule. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules